# how to find upper bound and lower bound of quadratic equation

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, lower-bounds, upper-bound

I am relatively new to algorithms, I wrote one pattern matching algorithm and its running time is $O(n^2)$, I tried it by step count method, direct method and also the constant method which all yields same results. Anyhow now I am writing the upper and lower bound for that, the equation which I get is

$$20n^2+11n+1$$
I need to find the

$$c_1n^2 \leq 20n^2+11n+1 \leq c_2n^2$$

Here I am stuck and needs some assistance, I have gone through a lot of examples, books, and youtube videos, but no one has any method to solve it instead of assumption and different ways. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT
Graph for the equation

[image: equation plotted for c1=32 c2=20 and n=1]

Comment: Hint: $1 \leq n \leq n^2$.

Comment: n greater then 1 is because the input will always be greater then 0? or is there any other reason for that?

Comment: Your algorithm operates on some input whose length is $n$. Can an array have negative length? Can it have length zero? Can it have non-integer length? Try thinking beyond the formulas.

Comment: just wanted to confirm as i was thinking the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n \geq 1$ (since $n$ is the input length), we have
$$
20n^2 \leq 20n^2 + 11n + 1 \leq (20+11+1)n^2 = 32n^2.
$$
Put differently, for all $n \geq 1$, the function $f(n) = 20n^2 + 11n + 1$ is bounded from below by $20n^2$ and from above by $32n^2$. This shows that $f(n) = \Theta(n^2)$.

Note also that when $n$ is large, $f(n)$ gets very close to $20n^2$. Indeed,
$$
1 \leq \frac{f(n)}{20n^2} \leq 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

Comment: in this case the c1=32 and n is 1, and for the c2 how do we solve it. Also i see you adding $n^2$  to 11 and 1, is it assumption that it still is greater or there is any reason behind this?

Comment: These are high-school inequalities. If you forget about the connection to computer science, I am sure you will be able to prove them.

Comment: i plotted it on graph and get this graph as a result, can you please have your expert look. Thanks alot for your patience and help in this regard. I also noticed that the intersection lies between 25 and 30 for the upper bound

Comment: I am unable to see any graph.

Comment: sorry, added with edits, i used another tool n now its showing the intersection point as 32.

Comment: The intersecting point is $n=1$, $f(n)=32$. That's not too surprising given the calculation above.

Comment: From where does O(1/n) come?

Comment: It comes from the additional $11n+1$, when divided by $20n^2$.

Comment: I didn't understand can you please elaborate this

Comment: I'm not really sure how to elaborate more. The formula for $f(n)$ gives that $\frac{f(n)}{20n^2} = 1 + \frac{11n+1}{20n^2}$, and the latter summand is $O(1/n)$, indeed $\Theta(1/n)$.